# Blacklisting specific roads from Google Maps/Mapquest?

Tags: google-maps

I'm looking to build a custom view of a Google Maps type of application for providing directions, but I need to blacklist specific roads or sections of roads.  I'm not talking just avoiding highways or Toll Roads.  I've been looking through the Google Maps and Mapquest APIs but haven't found anything of use yet.

Initially I'm just looking to manually blacklist specific roads that I do not want to drive on, but eventually would like there to be some sort of automatic detection or suggestion.

Is there built-in functionality to support blacklisting specific roads in Google Maps or Mapquest? Or is there any known way to hack it together?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in another answer, this functionality is not directly available in the Google Maps API. However, I've been thinking about it, and had a couple of work-around ideas in the "hacking it together" category. Both of these rely on version 3 of the Google Maps API.

1. When requesting the directions, set provideRouteAlternatives to true. Loop through the alternatives. Check if that route passes through one of your roadblocks. If it does, discard that route and try the next one.
2. For each roadblock, set up in advance one or more alternate points to route through. For example, if you want to avoid a certain bridge, identify one or more alternate bridges to use. Now, if a route passes through one of your roadblocks, add the alternate point for the for roadblock as a waypoint (with stopover set to false). Now run the directions again and they should avoid the roadblock and use the alternate.

Neither of these methods are optimal, but depending on your situation, they might work for you.

Comment: Add stopover=false doesn't garatee that. According with docs:

stopover (optional) indicates whether this waypoint is a actual stop on the route (true) or instead only a PREFERENCE to route through the indicated location (false). Stopovers are true by default.
Sorry for bad formatting.

Answer (score 5):

There is an open feature request about this issue on the Google Maps API Issue Tracker:

- [Roadblock definitions into GDirections as coordinate points](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=214)

The issue has been acknowledged by Google, but it remains open. You may want to vote up the issue to signal to Google the demand for this feature.

Comment: From what I understand, the report you linked me to is about avoiding highways, which has actually been added recently.  Did you mean to link to http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=214&q=roadblock&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal

Comment: Oops... Thanks for noting. Fixed the link.

Comment: The request has been there since 2008 - seems like it's not gonna happen.

Answer (score 4):

I think mapquest lets you do this, see http://www.mapquestapi.com/directions/#output 
and check out the section for mustAvoidLinkId's and tryAvoidLinkId's

Answer (score 0):

I tried all google maps alternatives, and none of them allows the possibility to define road that avoids certain road except Here maps. I am delighted with this solution and it solved all my problems https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/route-avoiding-links-and-areas.html

You don't need to blacklist the whole road, you can blacklist only some part of that road and the map will try to avoid that if possible.