# Android map navigation

Tags: maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Hi I am new to programming so please bear with me.

Basically, I want to create a map for Android devices that load markers and navigate from point A to B while avoiding the markers. It is ok if the path is not the shortest.

I have tried loading markers from geojson file using both google map and mapbox with no problems. Now, what can I do to customize navigation within the app itself? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it does not appear that this feature has direct support from the API. Please see these answers for alternate suggestions:

[Google API (directions) - creating routes that avoid certain points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19144100/google-api-directions-creating-routes-that-avoid-certain-points#19618494)

[Blacklisting specific roads from Google Maps/Mapquest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440967/blacklisting-specific-roads-from-google-maps-mapquest?noredirect=1&lq=1)