# Google Maps API - Ignore Streets in Path Planning

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to ignore specific streets in the path planning process of the google maps api? I want to build an application where specific streets can be marked as barriers and furthermore an alternative route should be offered. 
If not, can someone suggest an alternative to the google maps api where it's possible (for android development)?

Comment: do you want to a void some streets when you create a route for a specific destination ? is that what you are asking

Comment: yes, exactly. i.e. to avoid a route with stairs as a wheelchair user (in walking mode)...

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440967/blacklisting-specific-roads-from-google-maps-mapquest

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the [**directions api**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) and set way points in a way to avoid certain streets.