# Google Maps API (for Android): Can I get directions to *avoid* a waypoint?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I see that there are decent instructions for setting directions going *through* one or more waypoints, but can is there a way to *avoid* a location?

For example, let's say I am trying to get directions from Wichita, KS to Denver, CO (as here:  https://goo.gl/oziVIS).  But let's say I want to avoid going through Byers, CO (the small town at the center of the map here:  https://goo.gl/K1bDAh).  Is there a way I can do through the Directions API (or maybe the Maps APIv2)?

I'd be happy with something like, "don't come within 10 miles of this lat/long".

Comment: There is a [feature request post](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=214) in gmaps-api issue tracker, or you can try to suggestions from [this StackOverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2457979/4195406).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the answer is, "No" (or maybe "Not yet").

Based on the comment above, and the feature request here:  https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=214