# Driving directions for “truck” in google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I work for a company which helps trucking companies in optimizing their routes. I am using Google Maps API, v3 to determine optimal route between two points. Here is the business case I need help with:

- Google maps provides the optimal route from A to B when traveling by “car”.
- Our customers has “trucks” which cannot go on all the streets. Example:      Narrow streets, or low bridge.

To find optimal truck driving route, I plan to do the following:

- Mark the constrained spaces (narrow streets, low bridge, etc) as a barrier in google map. I was able to do so using DirectionService and DirectionRenderer APIs.
- Now ask Google routing engine to give me routes from A to B avoiding these barriers. I am not sure how to do that.

[Map only with Barriers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g50e8.png),
[Map with route passing through barrier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58Lzg.png).

Comment: Check the answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2457979/6139832, should solve your question.

Comment: You know what, there is long debate (started 9 years back in 2008) on having blocked road feature in google maps API. I have been following this issue at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35816642 but so far no updates from google.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blacklisting specific roads from Google Maps/Mapquest?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440967/blacklisting-specific-roads-from-google-maps-mapquest)

Comment: have you find soultion?